# Extends Java GraphQL schema type query in other module(jar)

Tags: java, graphql

I've a jar with GraphQL api and the schemas of this api. But i want to extends this api with a custom query. I created a

my-custom-queries.graphqls

```
type Query {
    myCustomQueryHerer(): [String]
}
```

Other Module(jar dependency)

```
type Query {
   queryOne(): String
   queryTwo(): Int 
}
```

The schema parser(graphql-java) identify both definitions but ignore my customization, keeping only the definitions made in the jar dependency.

Is there a way to add a query in the type Query schema, extending the settings made in the api(jar)?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Just mark the type with extend, that way you can add or change a type, even if it is in another lib.

```
extend type Query {
   myCustomQueryHerer(): [String]
}
```